# Some events completed make another event in python

Tags: python, algorithm, google-app-engine, events

I am currently under a hard problems.

Say that I have 2+ events, such as:

- (A): User do an action A
- (B): User do an action B

Each event is separated from the other and can be triggered from web request by user, and I do not know their order (which one occurs first).

Then, when both of A and B are occurred, it will fire another event called C: A + B => C

Is there any programming model or library make it easier in Python, I prefer pure python just because I am working with GAE.

I have thought about an usage of blinker with some addition codes, but it is still much of works.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since blinker is pure Python, using it on GAE should be quite feasible.

So you're left with the issue of triggering a signal when **two** other signals have been received -- an `and gate`, which I believe blinker doesn't provide -- definitely not when the incoming signals can come "well separated" in time and space.

So I'd define a model such as:

```
class AndGate(ndb.Model):
    a_received = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    b_received = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

using `users.get_user().userid()` as the id in its entities' key.

Then we'd have `signal(A).connect(got_a)` and `signal(B).connect(got_b)` with

```
def got_a(*_):
    k = ndb.Key('AndGate', users.get_user().userid())
    ag = k.get()
    if ag is None:
        AndGate(a_received=True, b_received=False, key=k).put()
        return
    if ag.b_received:
        k.delete()
        signal('C').send('')
    else:
        ag.a_received = True
        ag.put()
```

This looks a bit redundant with just two signals, I'm thinking forward to gates with `N>2` signals but you can surely simplify this if that's not an issue for you.

Yes there's work left to do -- atomic transactions if needed, periodic "garbage collection" tasks looking for `gates` where only one signal was received and are older than some threshold X and reporting about them, and so on.  But, it doesn't seem "much of works" to me, if I understood your specifications correctly.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for. I just wonder a bit about atomic transactions, I can do it well with mysql, this is first time I work with NDB.

Comment: Since you're dealing w/a single entity, the tiniest of entity groups:-), you just need to add the decorator `@ndb.transactional` before the `def`.  Only if you had to transact over multiple entities would you have to ensure they're in a single entity group, i.e, share one common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

1.- Avoid a race condition: If you're using a DB use a transaction/lock table/lock row to write A or B, if you are using threads use Threading.Lock() or something similar

2.- Check inside the transacction/lock if the trigger condition is met, and then      execute it.

```
@lock
def a():
    do_a
    if b:
        do_c

@lock
def b():
    do_b
    if a:
        do_c
```